# Is it possible to directly translate or rotate a Graphics or Graphics3D object?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, geometric-transform

I have seen the documentation for `Translate` (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate.html), which allows one to translate a graphics primitive (like `Circle`, `Cone`, etc.) and then apply `Graphics[]` or `Graphics3D[]` to it. E.g.-

```
Graphics[Translate[..., {1, 0}]]
```

Q: But what I want to know is whether one can translate (or rotate) an existing `Graphics` object, something like:

```
Translate[Graphics[...], {1, 0}]
```

In particular, I have the `Graphics3D` output of a `ParametricPlot3D[]` call that I want to translate in space. I don't want to go into the definition of the  `ParametricPlot3D[]` and translate the individual quantities inside. That is cumbersome, and might even lead to errors.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: try `MapAt[Translate[#, {1, 0}] &, {1}]@Graphics[...]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way like this.

```
g = ParametricPlot3D[{x*y, x, y + x}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];
Show[g, Graphics3D[
  GeometricTransformation[g[[1]], 
   RotationTransform[Pi/3, {1, 0, 0}]]]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please tell me why exactly you use `g[[1]]` instead of using `g` itself? I didn't even know that a Graphics object like `g` was indexed.

Comment: @ap21 we can use `g[[1]]//FullForm` and `g[[2]]//FullForm` to see the structure of `g`, especially  the structure of `GraphicsComplex`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, which I prefer when I chain multiple transforms to a `Graphics` object.

It's along the lines of @kglr's comment, but use a convenience functor that operates on the 1st part of a `Graphics`-headed expression (or, more generally, an expression with any head as long as it contains [part](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) $1$, i.e. *not* of the form `f[]`):

```
m = OperatorApplied[MapAt, {2, 3, 1}][1]; (* MMA 12.1+, or *)
m = Curry[MapAt, {2, 3, 1}][1];           (* MMA 11+ *)
```

`g =`[`OperatorApplied`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OperatorApplied.html)`[MapAt, {2, 3, 1}]` is an applicative that permutes arguments of [`MapAf[f, expr, n]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) into `g[n, f, expr]`. The argument order permutation `{2,3,1}` isn't very intuitive to read. It means that the 2nd argument of `g` will be passed to `MapAt` as its 1st argument, because $2$ is at the position $1$ in the list; `g`'s 3rd argument will be the 2nd to `MapAt`; and, finally, `g`'s 1st argument will be the `MapAt`'s 3rd, the last. This 1st argument of `g` is then curried to literal $1$ by the partial application syntax `g[1]`, completing the definition of `m`. Either `m[f, expr]` or `m[f][expr]` is then rewritten by MMA into `MapAf[f, expr, 1]`. This captures the essential idea of this wrapper:

```
In[...]=  m[transform][graphics["directives", "options", "..."]]
Out[...]= graphics[transform["directives"], "options", "..."]
```

Then I use the `m` in a chain of postfix transforms like this:

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[{{-1, 0}, {0, 2}, {1, 0}},
                         {Thick, Blue, Line[{1, 2}], 
                                 Orange, Line[{2, 3}],
                                 Magenta, Line[{3, 1}]}],
     ImageSize -> Small, Axes -> True
  ] (* // Normal *)(* -- if you want to dismantle the GraphicsComplex. *)
% // m[Scale[#, {1, -2}] &] //
     m[Rotate[#, Pi/6] &] // 
     m[{#, Translate[#, {1, 0}]} &]
% // Options (* The options are preserved: m[] is applied to directives only. *)
m = .
```